# bit map scaling

Tags: c#

I have bitmap of 24*24 pixels, I want to resize the bitmap dynamically 48*48 pixels or 5*5 pixels. How to do this with out losing the information

Comment: You want to resize a 24*24 pixels to 5*5 pixels without losing information. *scratching head*. If you find a solution you may win the turing award..

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(@"C:\Test1.bmp");
Bitmap result = new Bitmap(48, 48); 
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(result))
    g.DrawImage(bm, 0, 0, 48, 48);
result.Save(@"C:\Test2.bmp");
```

Typically scaling/Resizing images does change the quality of the new image...

Comment: the problem is that i have created a bitmap contains a  square, If the size of the bitmap is 10*10, the square will be displayed. If i give the bitmap size has 5*5, two edges of the square are missed

Answer (score 0):

You will lose information. To give *the impression* you are not losing as much information you need to use [anti-aliasing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_anti-aliasing). Iterate over the *original image* and consolidate the pixels which will become *one pixel in your final image* by taking the average of their colours.